# Could private states work

Tags: geopolitics

I'm thinking about a world where states are managed by companies and whoever can decide to switch state, staying between the conditions described by the contract each person have to sign when they join a state.

They should work just like the nowadays internet companies work.
If you don't like the company for whatever reason you can change it. But you may have binding contracts that keep you with a specific company for a minimum amount of years.

The tricky part is that I'd like to make this idea work without the constraint of having each state own a territory, because I'd like to make the switch as effortless as possible.

Could this model work and how could it work without requiring people to move to different countries when they want to change?

Comment: You might want to check the [TV series *Incorporated*](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Incorporated_(TV_series)). It uses a similar idea. And the outcome is exactly as predicted by Amadeus in his answer.

Comment: might want to read a book called SNow Crash because that is exactly what happens, you can live on your countries territory but you don't have to. However if you don't you miss out on many things like protection.

Comment: How do you envision your system applying to children? They can't sign a contract because they are minors. When they turn 16 or 18 do they get automatically signed up to the state their parent/guardian is in? Or do they get to choose? Alternatively, 16 year old may be clueless know-nothings to the company bean-counters (e.g. the company is an an engineering firm and the kid studied ballet and fine arts at school): why would a state want or need them?

Comment: *"If you don't like the company for whatever reason you can change it":* Maybe for the first 5 minutes of company rule; afterwards the rules will be unilaterally altered, in the interest of the serfs, of course, to provide life-long stability. In the absence of a state (or in general in the absence of a ruler with power over both parties) there is no such thing as a contract, because there is nobody to enforce it. That's why in our admittedly fallen world citizens don't have contracts with their countries; they are unconditionally subjected to the judicial decisions of their countries.

Comment: An interesting point here is what counts as a company, currently that is regulated in laws by the states where the companies are based. Could I unilaterally declare that I'm a company/state and legalize murder for my citizens? What prevents this?

Comment: Have you given any thought to what a private state *means*?  For example, contracts between individuals and a country are only honored in other countries via treaty.  Who is enforcing your "binding" contracts?  Also, if one company "invades" another company, what happens (given the lack of territory to make such an "invasion" simple)?

Comment: Which country are you thinking of signing up for?

Answer (score 4):

#### It would be difficult to devise this political scenario.

You can't make "contracts" work without some sort of collective, one that is more powerful than either Party in the contract, to enforce the terms of the contract, and typically to restrict the terms allowed in contracts.

Without such an entity, the more powerful Party in the contract can violate it at will; without punishment. For a contract to be any more than an empty promise, the weakest Party in a society must have some Court system they can use to force ***any*** other Party in a contract, even the most rich and powerful, to comply with the terms of the Contract. At least a credible *threat* to do that.

You also have the problem that ***Rights*** are enforced by the State, and these indirectly (by various court decisions) restrict what we can even make Contracts to do: In the USA, you cannot have a contract that requires somebody to break a law, or allows an employer to break a law.

For an example of the latter, a USA employer cannot have their employment contract say the employee waives their right to sue for sexual harassment (Heck, if we allowed that, I'd bet money some employment contracts would require sexual favors as part of the job.)

A private (meaning non-governmental) employment contract cannot force employees to accept violations of workplace safety, they cannot require employees to risk their lives (or sacrifice them). (Such requirements can be part of military service, but are treated differently, and other restrictions  still apply: On the front lines a commander can order a female soldier into lethal combat, but cannot order her to have sex with him.)

Contracts are useless and meaningless to people that have zero chance to appeal to power to get them enforced. They are empty promises to the 99% if the only people that can enforce them are the rich and already powerful.

Without **enforceable** restrictions on what terms are allowed in the contract, the rich and powerful have you trapped and can collude so there IS no alternative: For example, every State contract (by agreement of the Rulers of States) demands 90% of your income. None of the States dare allow anything else even if they wanted to: The rest of the States have agreed to shut down all Trade with any member that does that.

By collusion among States with greedy and power hungry leaders, I think your system will quickly develop into a lot of oppression and slavery with no escape for the citizens. Sure, they're free to switch from one slave owner to another: But their contract says to do so, they must pay a fee equivalent to five years of their salary; and **every** State's contract says the same thing.

Comment: You're right. Companies as states with contracted citizens (in name only) is a recipe for slavery, The Rights you mention under US Law would soon be waived under contract. To improve working conditions, increase opportunity, & other managerial claptrap. If not slavery, then certainly indentured labour. Uncomfortably dystopian.

Comment: @a4android yes, the whole premise of "competition" is that it drives down profits for ***all*** competitors. So it follows, logically, that if the law does not ***force*** you to compete, you will make more profits by colluding; and that includes stealing whatever value is created by the labor, creativity and innovation of your citizens, and giving them just enough of rewards and punishments to coerce them into continuing to produce that value. Whatever it may be in crops, mining, services, etc.

Comment: And thus we have religion and serfdom. Religion as an appeal to higher powers against the state, serfdom as obstacles in changing your overlords. It's all been done before.

Comment: @nzaman I don't think religion is ***against the state,*** historically most religions have striven to ***be the state.*** Kings and Emperors have nearly always, and famously, had to include the religion in their calculations and seek its endorsement, the Supreme Leader of the Religion in the state is the one that crowns the King. Serfdom is just another name for slavery; serfs were considered property tied to the land. Until the last few centuries, the Word Of God superseded all others, including Kings. That's what "King of Kings" means. And no King can overrule The Prophet in Islamic faith.

Comment: @Amadeus: Yes, that's how they _ended_. They all _started_ as an alternative source of authority to the state. Eventually they become popular and the state starts paying them attention; the next thing you know, the people in charge dump their, for want of a better word, constituents' wellbeing, and work to benefit themselves. Call it church, union, tribe, nation, parliament, it's all the same. Do also recall that the state has not been helpless or subservient; both the Holy Roman Emperor and Henry VIII ignored the Pope; Napoleon allegedly crowned himself before the Pope. contd...

Comment: @Amadeus: Serfs were technically bound to their Lord, who granted them a piece of land, in exchange for tribute and service (yes, in every meaning of the word). In theory, a serf who had problems with his lord could leave with his possessions to seek out a new lord. The first issue was, the lord could claim everything the serf owned, effectively leaving him with only the clothes on his back, sometimes not even that. Next, the serf was required to get a permit from his Lord to move out of his lands, which the Lord was under no obligation to provide. Sound like working for a modern corporation?

Comment: @nzaman I don't know that your claim about how religion "started" is supportable; religion and priests likely predate Kings. On Serfdom, from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serfdom: "On the other hand, if he chose to dispose of a parcel of land, the serfs associated with that land stayed with it to serve their new lord; simply speaking, they were implicitly sold in mass and as a part of a lot. This unified system preserved for the lord long-acquired knowledge of practices suited to the land. Further, a serf could not abandon his lands without permission..." Matches my memory: Bound to Land.

Comment: @Amadeus: Re: serfs, isn't that precisely what I said? Serfs weren't slaves, and would gladly help hunt escaped slaves as the one social group beneath them. In practice, they were worse off, since the slave owner at least had an economic interest in the slaves--he might want to sell them later; with serfs there was no obligation whatsoever: starve, die of disease, so long as the Lord got his dues. Re: religion, it varies; in some tribes the strongman came first, in others, the wise man. All modern religions, except, perhaps, Hinduism, are reactionary: their founders opposed the status quo.

Comment: @nzaman I did not think so, perhaps I was mistaken; I don't wish to discuss it further. I consider serfs to be slaves, which could also go free with the permission of their master and not otherwise. Serfdom is currently described as slavery by the UN. You are free to interpret this as you wish; I am done.

Answer (score 0):

What you're effectively talking about, if I understand you correctly, is a telecommuting citizenship, if there was a way to actually enforce the ability of the populous to change their State/Corporation at a whim it could work but, and it's a big but, only if the states were equipped to deal with the ebb and flow of human resources this would cause. Most companies, which is the base model here also the actual active model, can't, not won't but *can't*, absorb an influx of labour and most can't survive a walkout so a bad day at the office could destroy two or more countries at a stroke. I see the global set up as evolving in one of two directions neither particularly nice for the average civilian.

1. corporations will compete for labour until they consolidate effective territorial blocks at which point they basically own everyone in their zone of influence.
2. corporations will refuse to compete, at all, over anything, at which point everyone becomes a wage slave of one rank or another.